# Impact on FTP connection with ssl

Tags: unix, ftp

We have a little problem in recognising the change we need with a FTP server getting changed to FTPS.

I want to know what will be the change we need to made to continue the current functioning of the FTP scripts .

Do we need a ssl certificate on the server which has FTP scripts running.

Do we need a client compatible to ssl on the server which has FTP scripts running.

Also please let me know if there will be any other change we need to make in FTP commands

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

You need a server which supports FTPS, you need a certificate so that the server can identify itself inside the SSL handshake, you need a client which supports FTPS (not SFTP, which is a completely different thing). If you need to implement the client yourself you have to implement the `AUTH TLS`, `CCC` and `PROT` command additionally to the existing FTP commands.

Lots of clients support FTPS, like FileZilla or lftp. For a detailled description of the new commands see RFC4217, but in essence

- `AUTH TLS` starts the SSL handshake on the control channel so that login can be done protected
- `CCC` downgrades the control channel to plain text again. This might be necessary for NAT traversal with helpers
- `PROT P` defines that the data channel should also be done with SSL. Some servers enforce that the same SSL session as for the control channel has to be used.
- `PROT C` defines that the data channel should be clear, e.g. no SSL

Comment: Which client will be good FileZilla or lftp and can you tell me the format of the auth Tls and prot command